# Compile Using MONO - C# with Reference To A C# Library?

Tags: linux, mono, compiler-construction

I have a C# library (DLL)

```
//  ProgramLib.cs //
using System;

namespace ProgramLibrary
{
    public class Lib
    {
        public Lib()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Lib Created");
        }
    }
}
```

And I have the following console program

```
//  Program.cs //
using System;
using ProgramLibrary;

class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        ProgramLibrary.Lib lib = new ProgramLibrary.Lib();
    }
}
```

**In a linux environment, if both files reside in the same directory**

**What is the Mono compiler (mcs) command that compiles Program.cs with reference to ProgramLib.cs?**

**Thanks all!!**

Answer (score 30, accepted):

First compile ProgramLib to ProgramLib.dll, then reference it:

```
$ gmcs -t:library ProgramLib.cs
$ gmcs -r:ProgramLib.dll Program.cs
```

Comment: Anybody knows if there is a way to do this as a one liner?

Comment: @Renra: Create a solution with two project files and call xbuild?